# wpf listbox binding XElement not updated

Tags: c#, xaml

I am a beginner in C# / xaml and I do not understand everything in the binding, among others if it is necessary to notify or not to refresh the view.

In my code I use XML and XElement to store data. The xml contains one list of items (Properties), each of these items contains two lists (videoStreams and audioStreams).

When I add (or delete) one video the view is not refreshed. After if I add (or delete) one audio the view is refershed. The videos and audios lists are updated.
If, in the xaml code, I reverse audio and video lists, the problem is with audio.

Have you any idea about this problem?

My XML (extract)

```
<Root>
<Properties name="Node">
    <videoNode exclude="false">
        <rate minFrameRate="" maxFrameRate="" />
    </videoNode>
    <audioNode >
        <bitrateRange min="" max="" />
    </audioNode>
</Properties>
```

The xaml

```
    <ListBox Name="multiMaster" ItemsSource ="{Binding Elements[Properties]}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <ListBox Name="videoStreams" ItemsSource="{Binding Elements[videoNode]}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="stackVideo" Orientation="Vertical">
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
                <ListBox Name="audioStreams" ItemsSource="{Binding Elements[audioNode]}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="stackAudio" Orientation="Vertical">
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and the add function

```
    foreach (XElement childElement in oMMPNode.Descendants("Properties"))
{
    if (childElement.Attribute("id").Value == profileId)
    {
        XElement newVideo = new XElement("videoNode");
        childElement.Add(newVideo);

        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is necessary to notify. You need to map the XML data to a set of `ViewModels`. These should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and raise the corresponding event when values are changed, etc.

So, instead of XElement you would use:

```
public class XElementViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 

 public XElementViewModel(XElement data)
 {
    // initialize properties 
 }
 ... 
 // here you define all needed properties of XElement that you want to expose
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I try to do this.
But how can you explain that 2 parts of three are updated? And it seems to depend on position in xaml.

Comment: I failed to do it. No refresh is done.
Why some parts are refreshed, but not all. 
Whatever I do, first binding fails. For exemple if I add audio first in XAML (audio, video and audio again), the audio fails. It's always the first binding part

Comment: you need to create an ObservableCollection<XElementViewModel>, and bind to it in XAML. Then you just add/remove elements to/from this collection, you do not interact directly with the ListBox. In fact, you should remove the  Name="multiMaster" from the ListBox; if you need to retrieve the ListBox by name, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: each XElementViewModel should also have an "Elements" property of type XElementViewModel that would store the subelements.

Comment: I have no XElementViewModel at the moment, I just add(delete) XElement Node. Do you understand why it works for main node and audio and not for video?
And why it is for first group in XAML? If I put audio before video in XAML, it works for video and not audio.
I will try to code what you have said..

Comment: I have try to create XElementViewModel and ObservableCollection<XElementViewModel>, but nothing works.
Perhaps the class is not correct.
One difficulty is that nothing exists at the beginning. I can create several 'Properties', each one can have several audios and videos...